# Symfony2 kernel.response Event after controller annotations are executed

Tags: php, symfony

In order to modify a response cache control header I use a kernel.response event.
But when my listener gets called the controllers @cache annotation is not yet executed. How can I make sure that my listener gets called after all controller annotations are executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the order of listeners on the same event by setting priority. As you can see in the [`HttpCacheListener`](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/HttpCacheListener.php#L144-L150) of the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle, there is no explicit priority set. That means it has the default priority of `0`. So you can set your priority to any number higher than `0` (I recommend `10` or the like) to execute it before:

```
services:
    my_cache_listener:
        class: ...
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, priority: 10 }
```

Comment: It works. Thanx. Because listeners are called from highest to lowest priority I had to set a negative prio for my listener in order to get called after HttpCacheListener.